# chroot sftp not able to login

Tags: 12.04, ssh, chroot, openssh, sftp

I am trying to set up sftp access on my server and chroot the users into a samba share. When I edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add

```
Match Group sftpusers
 ChrootDirectory /srv/samba/share
 ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I am no longer able to log in. When I try to ssh into the server I get `Write failed: Broken pipe` and my sftp client says the `username and password are not accepted by the server`

If I comment out those lines I am able to log in via ssh and sftp again.

`/srv/samba/` is rwxr-xr-x root root

`/srv/samba/share` is rwxrwxr-x root sftpusers

Anyone know what I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`ChrootDirectory /srv/samba/share` should have been `ChrootDirectory /srv/samba`